# PHP echo'ed navbar items doesn't appear after deleting cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I made a simple Registration/Login script. It worked really well, but now, I can't echo an HTML tag (an anchor-tag). It worked before I implemented the deletion of a cookie. Here's my nav code:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper z-depth-1">
   <a href="index.php" class="brand-logo center">Todo <i class="material-icons right">add_circle_outline</i></a>
   <h6 id="loginName" class="valign-wrapper"><?php echo "Eingeloggt als: ". $_COOKIE['user']; ?></h6>
   <?php
      if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"])){
          echo '<a href="register.php" class="right" id="register">Registrieren</a><a href="login.php" class="right" id="login">Einloggen</a>';
      }else {
          echo '<a href="logout.php" class="right" id="logout">Ausloggen</a>';
      }
      ?>
</div>
```

I set the cookie, after a successful login:

```
 if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = :feldwert";
    $kommando = $db->prepare($sql);
    $wert = $username;
    $kommando -> bindParam(':feldwert', $wert);
    $kommando -> execute();
    if($kommando->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "Benutzer existiert!";
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username ='".$username."';";
        $erg = $db->query($sql);

        foreach ($erg as $row){
            $user = $row["username"];
            $pass = $row["password"];

            if(password_verify($password, $pass)){
                setcookie("user", $user, time() + 60*60*12);
                header("Location: index.php");

            }else {
                echo "Falschen Benutzernamen oder Passwort eingegeben!";
            }
        }
```

My logout-script looks like this:

```
<?php

setcookie("user","", 0);
header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

And even if this wouldn't delete the cookie, I removed it manually (or like with a firefox-addon), and there's still no anchor-tags.

Comment: use unset($_COOKIE['user']); setcookie('user', null, -1);

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). In your first query, you're using prepared statements correctly (using parameter for the username) but in the second query, you just insert the user data straight in the query.

Comment: Uhm, the "unset" doesn't makes my anchor tags listed on the nav. And what about: setcookie('user', null, -1); ? Isn't it the same, than unset($_COOKIE)?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, you're right, I need to change that. But first I want to get my full nav-elements back ;/

Comment: setcookie('user', null, -1);  expires the cookie.

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni Okay, it seems to remove / expires the cookie, because after clicking on "logou" (which will only be shown if the cookie is set), the logout-link is gone, but still the other 2 links (Login & Register) are gone. It has to be something with the if-statemet..

Comment: `unset()` just removes it from PHP's super global. It doesn't mean that the browser removes/invalidates it. To invalidate it for the browser, you need to set the cookie to an empty value (like an empty string) and set the expire date to sometime on the past. However, I've heard that some browsers doesn't accept `null` as a value (must be string so set it to an empty string) and `-1` isn't a valid timestamp, so set it to something like `time() - 100000`. Example: `setcookie('user', '', time() - 100000);`